# styling facebook comment widget

Tags: css, facebook-social-plugins

I need to add some css styling to the comments widget in a facebook application. I use the following code snippet to use the widget

" num_posts="10" width="500" scrolling="yes">

I need to provide a way for users to scroll to view more comments than fits in the initial container size.

Is there a way to do it at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't possible using the comments social plugin. Social Plugins load as iframes within your page, and there isn't a hook to allow this kind of behaviour.

If I've understood correctly what you're asking for isn't a CSS change, it's a behavioural change that would require JS to lazy load new comments.

You'll have to roll your own, using the Graph API to fetch the comments as you need them